# android volley form post requests are always out of order

Tags: android, post, android-volley

so i am using volley to connect to a backend and for some reason they need the form request data to be in a certain order the server wont accept it. unfortunately no matter how i put my data into the hashmap when overriding getParams they always come out in the same, incorrect order causing me to be unable to make a request. is there a way for me to order it, or just create my own string and send that? thanks

Comment: Try using LinkedHashMap instead HashMap . And form data is basically key value so it should not depend on sequence

Comment: oh yea LinkedHashMap worked thanks! I switched it to that and started working perfectly, i know its supposed to be key value but when i send it out of order it just sends back an error. its pretty weird